# How do I make my website on Google App Engine accessible to visitors in China?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

China blocks appspot -- How do I get around this?

Assuming the censorship was not an issue, how bad are the latency issues?

Comment: I don't think you do. And I imagine the latency would be bad since Google wouldn't have any App Engine servers in China.

Comment: does china block the domain? or all of google's IPs? ...I'm guessing the latter

Comment: Set up a proxy with an ISP in Hong Kong?

Comment: it might help if you ask china to stop hacking google's servers...

Answer (score 1):

Assuming Google has, and routes to, Datacenters in Asia, the latency should be reasonable.

The reverse proxy to avoid the firewall should be in a country that does not censor and is as near as possible to the target area.

In those conditions, google would choose a datacenter near your reverse proxy, and the latency is rtt(google<->proxy)+rtt(user<->proxy)

But you really have to try this out.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look to [chinasb](http://translate.google.com/translate?js=n&prev=_t&hl=en&ie=UTF-8&layout=2&eotf=1&sl=zh-CN&tl=en&u=http://app.chinasb.org/); some info [here](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Google+Apps/thread?tid=3bc59498df549020&hl=en).